# Renaming buffered layers automatically as buffered value using QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I am building a model which needs buffer on a layer. The value of that buffer sometimes changes (I change it manually in that model). After buffering, I would like to rename this layer (rename layer - function) as 'Name XY' (Buffered "BufferValue XY"). The "BufferValue XY" shall be the value, which I took at the buffer function before this rename function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a variable to control the buffer distance and also use that inside the output file name.

Setting the output as a **Pre-calculated Value** we can set the file name to something like:

```
 'C:\\temp\\'||'Name (Buffered '||to_string(@BUFFDIST)||').shp'
```

**@BUFFIST** is the input buffer distance variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works out. The "Numbers" Input is the right one for this.